# Making a non-overlapping bubble chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bubble-chart

I am currently trying to make a bubble chart in Matplotlib where the bubbles do not overlap, so packing the circles/bubbles in the chart, approximately like

[image]

What I thought might work:

- Plot the first data-point using x = 1, y = 1
- Randomly plotting the other data-points by calculating the radius of the bubble given the scalar value as to avoid overlapping

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following would be a brute-force approach.
You can first place all circles on a grid, with a gridspacing as large as twice the maximum radius of any of the circles.
[image]

Then you let the circles do a random walk and check in each step if the "potential energy" of the bunch of cicles has become smaller and if the positions obtained are valid (i.e. no overlaps).

```
if (e < self.E and self.isvalid(i)):
```

As a "potential"  we can simply use a square radial function.

```
self.p = lambda x,y: np.sum((x**2+y**2)**2)
```

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create 10 circles with different radii
r = np.random.randint(5,15, size=10)

class C():
    def __init__(self,r):
        self.N = len(r)
        self.x = np.ones((self.N,3))
        self.x[:,2] = r
        maxstep = 2*self.x[:,2].max()
        length = np.ceil(np.sqrt(self.N))
        grid = np.arange(0,length*maxstep,maxstep)
        gx,gy = np.meshgrid(grid,grid)
        self.x[:,0] = gx.flatten()[:self.N]
        self.x[:,1] = gy.flatten()[:self.N]
        self.x[:,:2] = self.x[:,:2] - np.mean(self.x[:,:2], axis=0)

        self.step = self.x[:,2].min()
        self.p = lambda x,y: np.sum((x**2+y**2)**2)
        self.E = self.energy()
        self.iter = 1.

    def minimize(self):
        while self.iter < 1000*self.N:
            for i in range(self.N):
                rand = np.random.randn(2)*self.step/self.iter
                self.x[i,:2] += rand
                e = self.energy()
                if (e < self.E and self.isvalid(i)):
                    self.E = e
                    self.iter = 1.
                else:
                    self.x[i,:2] -= rand
                    self.iter += 1.

    def energy(self):
        return self.p(self.x[:,0], self.x[:,1])

    def distance(self,x1,x2):
        return np.sqrt((x1[0]-x2[0])**2+(x1[1]-x2[1])**2)-x1[2]-x2[2]

    def isvalid(self, i):
        for j in range(self.N):
            if i!=j: 
                if self.distance(self.x[i,:], self.x[j,:]) < 0:
                    return False
        return True

    def plot(self, ax):
        for i in range(self.N):
            circ = plt.Circle(self.x[i,:2],self.x[i,2] )
            ax.add_patch(circ)

c = C(r)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
ax.axis("off")

c.minimize()

c.plot(ax)
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Because of the random walk nature of this, finding the solution will take a little time (~10 seconds in this case); you may of course play with the parameters (mainly the number of steps `1000*self.N` until a solution is fixed)  and see what suits your needs.